# Spring Batch application is scheduled to run every minute but gets exited immediately?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I have the Spring Batch application that uses the task scheduler and currently set to run every 1 minute.

As of now, the application schedule (cron job) is hard coded as highlighted below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="simpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleAsyncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="springSchedulingLauncher" class="com.javacodegeeks.example.scheduler.JobScheduler"></bean>
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" />
    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="springSchedulingLauncher"
                        method="launch"
                        cron="* 1 * * * *"
        />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
</beans>
```

below is the Job Definition

```
    <job id="myJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" restartable="true">
        <step id="step1" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <tasklet ref="myTasklet">
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
    
    <bean id="myTasklet" class="com.javacodegeeks.example.util.MyTasklet">
    </bean>
    
    </beans>
```

below is the java scheduler code

```
public class JobScheduler {
    @Scheduled(cron = "* 1 * * * *")
    public void launch() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting Launch");
        String[] str = {"META-INF/spring/context-config.xml","META-INF/spring/job-config.xml"};
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(str);
        Job job = (Job) ctx.getBean("myJob");
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("jobLauncher");
        try{
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Job Execution Status: "+ execution.getStatus());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed Launch");
    }
}
```

and the App.java (main method) is given below

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting Main");
        System.out.println("Completed Main");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` with the `JobLauncher` which runs jobs asynchronously in a background thread. Hence, the `run` method returns immediately. If you want to wait for the job to finish, you have to use a synchronous `TaskExecutor` (which is the default setting).

Please refer to the reference documentation here: [Configuring a JobLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher).

Comment: Can you please help me with the XML configuration with TaskExecutor ?

Comment: You have already configured a task executor in your XML config and set it on the `JobLauncher`. What, specifically, are you looking for?